# How do I open terminal or browser windows in the current workspace?

Tags: macos, spaces, quicksilver

Whenever I open a new terminal or browser window via QuickSilver it switches control back to the last used workspace. I would like to always open in the current workspace, how do I do that?

I am on OS Mavericks. Please keep in mind that existing answers about modifying Expose or Spaces settings do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

I've set up Alfred to open new Terminal and Safari windows in the current workspace by having it call an Apple Script. I'd expect that you could do the same in Quicksilver. These are the scripts I've used:

Safari:

```
tell application "Safari"
  make new document
  activate
end tell
```

Terminal:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "uptime"  
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

here is [my solution](http://maxyun.net/index.php/2014/08/15/new-safari-windows-with-specific-url-on-current-workspace-via-alfred/) with little tweak.
on that link, there is dropbox link of a Alfred workflow.

- via Alfred
- pop up new safari on current workspace, and make it front
- (optional) if needed, open specific URL //currently this script valid for just 1 URL address.
- (optional) in case of specific URL, no need of “http://”